# D3 - Why do circles drawn on top of a map not appear in the correct position?

Tags: d3.js

I developed an interactive map of my city but noticed that images I added did not appear in the correct location and I've add to adjust the latitude and longitude by a small amount - .005. That works but why do I need to do it? Are the images affecting positioning?

```
 circles.selectAll("circle")
 .data(bottom)
 .enter()
.append("image")
.attr("xlink:href", function(bottom) { 
      return categoryTable [bottom.field_category];
}) // end attr
.attr("width", 32)
.attr("height", 32)
.attr("transform",function(bottom){
    return"translate("+projection([bottom.field_lng - .005,bottom.field_lat + .005])+")"; // adjust test
}) // end transform attr
```

Comment: The coordinates that you specify designate the top left corner of the image by default. If you want to position the center, you'll have to adjust accordingly.

Comment: Lars, Thanks ... I guess I need to calculate the relationship between pixels and degrees or do a rough approximation as I did.

Answer (score 0):

Building on @Lars' comment:

You don't need to calculate the conversions function a second time, since you're already doing the conversion in the projection method.  Since you know the size of the image in pixels, you know the offset in pixels to get it centred.  Just don't go running that pixel value through your projection method.

You could combine the two offsets (long/lat and centring) in one big transform attribute, like this:

```
.attr("transform",function(bottom){
    return "translate (-16,-16) translate("
        + projection([bottom.field_lng,bottom.field_lat])+")"; // adjust test
}
```

However, it would probably be easier to use the image's `x` and `y` attributes (both zero by default) for one type of positioning and translation for the other.  Something like [this fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/YBrE4/).

Since the array format of lat/long and the projection method work well with the syntax of the translate method, leave that as is and just add `.attr("x", -16).attr("y", -16)` when you create the image objects.  In fact, if all your image icons have the same size, you could just define a layout object at the top of your code, and add it to the objects in one attribute statement:

```
var imageAttributes = {height:32, width:32, x:-16, y:-16};
```

Then your initialization code would be:

```
circles.selectAll("circle")
   .data(bottom)
 .enter()
   .append("image")
   .attr("xlink:href", function(bottom) { 
      return categoryTable [bottom.field_category];
   }) // end attr
   .attr(imageAttributes)
   .attr("transform",function(bottom){
       return "translate(" 
                + projection([bottom.field_lng,bottom.field_lat])+")"; 
   }) // end transform attr
```

Comment: Hi Amelia, This is very helpful. I'll try it out tomorrow. Thanks for the tip.